# Vaadin - How to display Godaddy Seal code

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin8

I've been trying to show the seal of my Godaddy SSL certificate . I used Label , CustomLayout , Image, BrowserFrame and JavaScript.getCurrent().execute().

Those don't work.

The HTML code is :

```
**<span id="siteseal"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://seal.godaddy.com/getSeal?sealID=QatZVgMHgHTro1Zx5CzFh4oM5oqmchNB7lkqP6Hzf85vD73h1IaOety7c6dT"></script></span>**
```

The certificate is active and is valid .

I really appreciate your help.

Jose.

Comment: Have you checked the src your script tag refers to? Opening it with a browser shows the the javascript code is commented out.

Comment: Hi Michael,  thank you.  It is true,  have not notice that.  I will check this with Godaddy .